# Cannot open application via heroku (Using Ruby on Rails By Micheal Hartl, Ch 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have finished an application in Rails and trying to deploy on heroku, but facing an error that says: **The page you were looking for doesn't exist.**

The app runs locally though. I have also updated database and running heroku status says:

```
Production:   No known issues at this time.
Development:  No known issues at this time.
```

Comment: what do the heroku logs say? are you using rails_12factor?

Comment: Can you also post your console output when you deploy your app?

Comment: I did not commit and push to git so it was showing me error page. It works fine after pushing to git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across to same issue; after doing following change in production.rb located in`config/environments/production.rb` from

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

to

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

commit the new change.